# Can a PivotField position be determined from a Selection?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

If I select one of the PivotFields in the following PivotTable, is there a way to determine its position? For example, selecting Yc and deducing the position is 2.

```
Xa
---- Yb
---- Yc
-------- Za
-------- Zb
-------- Zc
Xb
---- Yd
-------- Ze
-------- Z5
```

Comment: Hello, 
Do you want to do this on VBA? your question is not clear. If so that's easy, just a loop through the Pivot fields and comparing that with your selected one and returning the position in the loop. Please explain if you need help.

Comment: Yes, VBA is tagged. How can you compare when the text values could be completely identical in different fields (for example, Yc=Yd?

Comment: As Peter mentioned, I meant the relative position of the selected field. I fyou are looking for the pivotfield, that should be enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make sure you're in the right range. Review Jon Peltier's excellent page on [pivot table ranges](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/). In your case, you want to restrict your cell selection to `RowFields`. The path to figuring out which position is to back out from which `Item` in which `Field`...

```
Option Explicit

Sub WhatPosition()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    Debug.Print "current cell selection is " & Selection.Address & _
                " = '" & Selection.value & "'"

    '--- is the selection within the row label range of the pivot table?
    If Not Intersect(Selection, pt.RowRange) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "selection position = " & StringToPivotFieldPosition(pt, Selection.value)
    Else
        Debug.Print "the selection is not within the pivot table"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function StringToPivotFieldPosition(ByRef pTable As PivotTable, _
                                            ByVal value As String) As Long
    Dim field As PivotField
    StringToPivotFieldPosition = 0
    For Each field In pTable.RowFields
        Dim item As PivotItem
        For Each item In field.PivotItems
            If item.Name = value Then
                StringToPivotFieldPosition = field.position
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next item
    Next field
End Function
```

Comment: Like I wrote in a previous comment, different fields could have completely identical texts and your loop will just assume you want the first of them.

Comment: In your example of Yc=Yd, the position is still =2. Doesn't matter which is picked up, the answer is still correct. Unless you're saying Yc=Ze ?